# Digital and analog servo reacting differently with arduino

Tags: arduino

I have some code controling an old analoge servo and all is working fine.

But when I got a new digital servo, it will not hold position, but return to 0.

Please help, what is needed?

Here is the basic code basen on Sweep:

```
#include <Servo.h> 
Servo myservo; 
int pos = 0;     

void setup() 
{ 
myservo.attach(A1);   
} 

void loop() 
{ 
for(pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos++)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Sorry but... What do you want to do? This sketch sets up a servo on channel A1, then moves it fast at the 0 position, then moves towards the 180 position (taking about 2.7 seconds), then it moves quickly to the 0 position, starting again. Is this what you want to do? Or you want to hold it in a fixed position? What position? How will you change it?

Answer (score 0):

Right after your for loop put:

```
while(1);
```

Before the closing bracket of the loop()
This will stop the program at that point and not keep running your for loop which declares pos = 0 each time.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question was a bit unpresice.

But I found out that there are one other way of controling a servo, and that is by using **writeMicroseconds** instead of myservo.write(90).

```
myservo.writeMicroseconds(1500);  //
```

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoWriteMicroseconds